# Display Filename in button text

Tags: c#, file, button, text

How to get the string in the button text?

```
private void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    ReadCSV(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    btn_open.Text = "filename here";

    string targetdirectory = "D:\\Projects";
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(target directory);
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Please improve your question. It's not clear what you are asking here

Comment: Sorry, i am new. I press on an open button and i can choose a csv file and show it in my dataGridview. After opening the file i want to change the open Button to the files name.

Comment: Ok. Can you just assign `btn_open.Text` to your `filename` string then?

Comment: It shows me the path of the file then.

Comment: If using `GetFileNameWIthoutExtension` correctly then you should see results like the ones here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx. Not sure why yours isn't working, although I can't see anywhere that you're assigning a filename? Can you edit your post to include all of your code?

Comment: I thought GetFileNameWIthoutExtension automatically assing to my file.. I dont know how to assign to my file.

Comment: `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` gets the fine name without extension to the `filename` string. Then you need to set it to button text like so: `btn_open.Text = filename;`.

Comment: Also, you need to pass a file path, not a directory, to the above method.

Comment: Thanks. Can i have a dynamic file path or how to handle new files?

Comment: That's as vague as you can be! Beside that's a different question? Please specify clearly.

Comment: New files are added to a specific directory. I want to choose one and open. The open button should show the name of the file. Thats what i mean with "dynamic file path". Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a file using `OpenFileDialog`, the `OpenFileDialog.FileName` contains the full path of the file selected.

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` does just that, getting the file name without extension. However you need to pass an actual file path, not a directory. If you pass a directory path, it will simply retrieve the innermost directory name which is not what your desired outcome.

So what you should do is;

- Get file name from `OpenFileDialog`.
- Pass *that* to the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` method.
- Set the resulting string as the button text.

Also the correct usage of `ShowDialog()` is to check the return value; it returns `true` if the user clicked `OK` button, and `false` otherwise.

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    btn_open.Text = file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working without: if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)    ==cant used with Dialog Result.

Comment: OK, I coded my example using WPF which is what I had opened, looks like you're on WinForms. So you can do `if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` which will achieve the same result.